# Difference between $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $C(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, notation

The definition for $C_0(\Omega)$ is continuous functions that vanish at the boundary of $\Omega$. When $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ the boundary is an empty set thus we have $C(\mathbb{R}) = C_0(\mathbb{R})$.

However some books define $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ to be continuous functions that vanish at infinity, then non zero constant functions will not be in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ but they will be in $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Are the two $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ different?

Comment: It seems it would depend on how you interpret $\mathbb{R}$, topologically. If you consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ with the standard topology, then the boundary of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\{\infty\}$.

Comment: No! The definition is "vanishes at infinity", meaning for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a compact set $K$ such that $|f|<\epsilon$ on $\Omega\setminus K$. Now if $\Omega$ happens to be bounded this is the same as vanishing on the boundary, but it's different for unbounded sets...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not the definition of $C_0$ I have used my whole life. The way I understand and use $C_0(\Omega)$ (and they way I have always seen it in the literature) is
$$
C_0(\Omega)=\{f\in C(\Omega):\ \forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists K\subset\Omega\ \text{ compact, with } |f(t)|<\varepsilon,\ t\in \Omega\setminus K\}.
$$
That is, functions that are arbitrarily small outside of a compact set. In other words, $C_0(\Omega)$ is the norm-closure of the set of continuous functions of compact support.

In particular, a $C_0$-function may be nonzero everywhere.